# Pacote puLP do python: como criar restrições usando a função de máximo

Tags: python

Estou escrevendo uma programação linear utilizando o pacote puLP do python. Estou com dúvidas na construção de uma restrição.

Para ilustrar o problema, imagine um quadrado medindo 100 x 100 cm. Eu tenho vários círculos com dimensões variadas. Preciso incluir estes círculos (não necessariamente todos eles) dentro do quadrado de forma a maximizar a soma da área dos diâmetros. Quando a primeira fileira é finalizada a segunda será inserida na parte superior, formando a segunda fileira, e assim sucessivamente, sempre considerando as seguintes restrições:

1. Cada circulo pode ser selecionado somente 1 vez e para apenas 1 fileira (nem todos os círculos precisam ser selecionados)
2. A soma dos diâmetros dos círculos não pode exceder o comprimento do quadrado.
3. A soma dos diâmetros máximos dos círculos de cada fileira não pode exceder a altura do quadrado
4. A soma da área dos círculos não pode ultrapassar a área do quadrado.

Minha dúvida está na restrição 3. Minha ideia é identificar o diâmetro máximo selecionado para cada fileira (pode ser a média também). A soma desses máximos não pode exceder o valor de 100 (que é a altura do quadrado). É possível criar este tipo de restrição? Se sim, como faço para escrevê-la.
Abaixo segue o código que já desenvolvi. Nela não está incluso a restrição 3.

Quem puder me ajudar agradeço imensamente.

```
'Variables'

    alocado = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("alocado",((n, t) for n, t in df.index),cat='Binary')

    model = pulp.LpProblem("Alocacao_na_pilha", pulp.LpMaximize)

'Objective Function'

    model += pulp.lpSum(alocado[n, t] * df.loc[(n, t), 'area'] for n, t in df.index),'z'

'Set'

    circle= df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
    filled= df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()

'Restrictions'

    for n in circle:
        model += pulp.lpSum(alocado[(n, t)] for t in filled) <= 1

    for t in filled:
        model += pulp.lpSum(alocado[(n, t)] * df.loc[(n, t),'d1'] for n in circle) <= 100

    model += pulp.lpSum(pulp.lpSum(alocado[n, t] for t in filled) * df.loc[(n, t), 'area'] for n in         circle) <= 1000

'Solving the problem'

    model.solve(pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(maxSeconds=1000, msg=1, fracGap=0))
```